# choosing the right size of a datatype?

Tags: mysql, sql

For example on a varchar datatype, I'm allowing usernames to a maximum number of characters of  25. Does that mean the optimal column is `varchar(25)`?

---

**EDIT**: Does it also mean that length of string = size of string?

Comment: Or `nvarchar`, if you want to support unicode usernames...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of a VARCHAR column in MySQL is not actually that important! Under most (all?) storage engines, the amount of storage required for each row **does not increase** as you the size of the column goes up to a maximum of `VARCHAR(255)`. Using a `VARCHAR(256)` or larger will use a single extra byte per row, which still isn't a lot. (At that point you may want to think about using a `TEXT` column anyway.)

As such, be generous with your column sizes. Avoid hard-coding non-technical limits (like a limit of 25 characters in a username) into the database -- if you change your mind later it's much easier to just change your validation code than it is to alter a potentially very large table. For usernames, for instance, I'd just set the column size to something medium-ridiculous like `VARCHAR(64)` to allow for future expansion. Just make sure that, if the same "data type" (e.g, username) appears elsewhere in the database, you use the same generous size consistently.

Answer (score -1):

Or just char(25) either way. But varchar(25) sounds fine.

Comment: I did not downvote you, but if I use char wouldn't that add extra space to the value if it's not exactly 25 characters?

Comment: yes but using varchar is going to add a byte onto every entry anyway so its a tradeoff

Comment: Using `CHAR()` can end up adding *literal* space characters to the input, not just using extra space on disk.